# ruby on rails loosing data even with git control

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, git, sqlite

Today i lost all the db data of my app (not the table, but the actual stuff in it) and i am asking myself a few question.

But first here a quick summary of what happened.

nb : i am using cloud9/rails app with sqlite.

1) starting to work on a new controller/model combo so i make a new branch with git

2) Major screw up on my branch, the more i fix the more i destroy.

3) checking out of the branch to master and destroy the branch (i didn't commit anything)

4) i notice that i still have the modified file in my workspace so i use the git clean command (don't remember exactly which option i used)

5) nothing is working anymore on my app. so i "revert" to an earlier commit.

6) everything is working again but i my DB is empty...not that the data are important (most of the data is ipso lorem plus a few integer) but i want to try to retrieve them anyway.

7) i fetch from bitbucket and reset hard to origin. the app is working but still no data.

So my questions are :

Where the db data are kept with ruby on rails ?
- git control don't save db data ?
- is there a way to recover the data ?
      if not : can i save the db date someway and fetch it in case of problem
-what going to happen in the future, each time i screw up i lost all data ?

ps: the data in itself is not that matters, its more the behavior i am trying to understand.
Thx for reading and sorry for my english.

Comment: If you did something like `git clean -f -d`, it will remove all of your local untracked files. Without knowing where your data files were located, it's impossible to say whether this was the reason for the data loss, but it's likely.

Comment: So my db:data (development.sqlite3 file) is considered untracked ? i was under the assumption that only pending modification were going to be erased. i did not modify my db:data during on this branch

Comment: Did your earlier commit have the data in it? If not, then by reverting you discarded it.

Comment: yes the data was included in previous commit (at least 20 of them) i backtracked them with git reset and still no data for my dev db